# Send Hex command to R2000 RFID reader

Tags: arrays, ruby, byte

In the configuration of R2000 RFID reader module, I have advanced during last times. Now I have a new question. If I want to get the antenna setting info I send an Hex command and module returns the next info:
A5 5A 00 0A 2b **22 11** 12 0D 0A
where data 22 11 are DByte1 DByte0 and means that antenna 1, 5, 10 and 14 are chosen. I don't know how to get this info from 22 11 Hex code.

DByte1 (Hex 22) means that antennas 10 and 14 are chosen
DByte0 (Hex 11) means that antennas 1 and 5 are chosen

How can I get 10,14 values from Hex 11 and 1,5 values from Hex 22 in Ruby?
How can I do the reverse action if I have set antenna 14 with Hex 20?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please see "[ask]" and the linked pages and "[mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)". We need to know what you've tried; Did you research this? If so, why didn't it help? If it helped, did you write code? If not, why? If so, what is the minimal code example that demonstrates the problem you're having? Currently it looks like you didn't try writing code and want us to write a tutorial describing what you need to do, which is off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

It's a simple binary format. `0x2211` is a 16-bit integer where each bit represents an antenna:

```
format('%016b', 0x2211)
#=> "0010001000010001"
#      ^   ^    ^   ^
#     14  10    5   1
```

So to figure out if an antenna is set, you just have to check if the corresponding bit is set to `1`:

```
n = 0x2211
n[0] == 1 #=> true
n[1] == 1 #=> false
n[2] == 1 #=> false
n[3] == 1 #=> false
n[4] == 1 #=> true
```

Note that the indices are 0-based, i.e. `n[0]` is antenna 1.

> How can I get 10,14 values from Hex 11 and 1,5 values from Hex 22 in Ruby?

You could extract the binary [`digits`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/Integer.html#method-i-digits), combine [`each`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/Array.html#method-i-each) digit with its 1-based index ([`with_index`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/Enumerator.html#method-i-with_index)), [`select`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/Enumerable.html#method-i-select) those bits that are set to `1` and extract their indices via [`map`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/Array.html#method-i-map):

```
0x2211.digits(2)                 #=> [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1]
      .each.with_index(1)        #=> [[1, 1], [0, 2], [0, 3], [0, 4], [1, 5], [0, 6], [0, 7], [0, 8], [0, 9], [1, 10], [0, 11], [0, 12], [0, 13], [1, 14]]
      .select { |b, i| b == 1 }  #=> [[1, 1], [1, 5], [1, 10], [1, 14]]
      .map(&:last)               #=> [1, 5, 10, 14]
```

Or using bit operators [`&`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/Integer.html#method-i-26) and [`<<`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/Integer.html#method-i-3C-3C):

```
antennas = []
0.upto(15) { |i| antennas.push(i + 1) if (0x2211 & (1 << i)) != 0 }
antennas #=> [1, 5, 10, 14]
```